# Error while using isFocused() inside a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a small question - I have a threaded chat client, for which I want to create an alert (beep sound). The alert will be triggered whenever the window is not in focus and a message is received. Right now I am just trying to get a message displayed, regardless of the focus status. If this works, I could replace the print statement with `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();`.

```
public class IncomingReader implements Runnable {
   public void run() {
      String message;
      Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 11);
      JTarea.setFont(font);
      try {
         while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //checkFocus();
            if (Jfrm.isFocused()) {
               System.out.println("focused");
            } else {
               System.out.println("not focused");
            }
            JTarea.append(message + "\n");

         }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println("errror run()");
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
}
```

Now whenever I do this, or else, I create a function `checkFocus()` having the same code, the compiler is giving me a

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ChatClient$IncomingReader.run(ChatClient.java:284)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't have any idea why this is happening and would appreciate any help given.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the line 284 of ChatClient.java? This is where you probably call a method on a null object. Also: you may not use Swing components in a background thread. All Swing components must be accessed from the EDT. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading

Comment: One of the variables being referenced in your code is null. Best bet would be to use a debugger to find out which one.

Comment: The 284 line is the the if statement, where it is check isFocused()..thanks for the suggestion, i didnt knew that, will change that, i think that's why i get so many error when i change a small code in the run() method. Thnks

Comment: Then, it means that `Jfrm` is null. Check how, where and when it is initialized. We don't have your code, so we can't help more.

Comment: @jb nizet thanks man...i understood the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The object `Jfrm` (JFrame):

```
if(Jfrm.isFocused())
```

is `null` probably.

Make sure you actually have a valid object, before calling a method on it.

Comment: Could u plz elaborate more on that. Why this error in threads, i checked the same isFocused for a window in a separate simple java program with while loop. It worked fine.